# Email and Addresses Missing

Tags: email, contacts

We suddenly lost about 75% of our contact's email and addresses. We've reset our SQL and it hasn't helped. In addition, some of the missing emails still work in our event registration section while others are not recognizing them as members. Has anyone else had this happen? Any known fixes? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds pretty unusual. Perhaps some more information would assist to attract a possible answer.
What CMS are you using (Drupal /Wordpress / Joomla?) and what version. And what version CiviCRM. With the missing emails that "still work in our event registration section" it may help if you explain that a little more. How exactly do they still work? Perhaps you could check those contacts to see if the email or addresses are still on the record at all, like when you edit the contact. Or is that information available in Mysql ?

Comment: Also, are you using any extensions?

Comment: If you look directly in the database tables, is that data still present? What do you mean by "reset our SQL"?

Comment: I think its time to look directly at the data tables ... and you have a backup, right?  Without knowing more about what is or is not in the mysql tables its really hard to make a diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. We were able to create a new DB from a backup. I probably should of posted this question here, but I started a new one. Maybe this log file can help me prevent loss in the future: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/random-data-loss-data-breach-user-error-database-failure-anyone-have-an-idea Thanks again!